# Viewing Historical Metadata of BigQuery Tables/Datasets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, metadata, database-metadata

Is there a way to view historical information about BigQuery tables over time? For example, if I wanted to check how the size of a table has changed? 
 
Attempts: 
None, because I am unaware if this is doable.

Comment: well you can query table at a point in time using time travel. Doc - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#query_data_at_a_point_in_time. But in your case i guess you need to build this custom functionality using time travel itself.

Comment: Yah @Mr.Batra I was looking at time travel but it only provides snapshots over the last 7 days. I guess I'll have to write a script locally or GCP to submit SELECT COUNT(*) queries and record them somewhere... yeesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tables you can now check on [TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage-timeline) with information for all tables in the current or specified project. This view contains metadata about historical table storage usage.

Comment: Nice to see Google finally implemented this feature! Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Depending specifically on what info you want to get, there are multiple ways of accomplishing this:

##### Time travel

As mentioned in [the comments to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296811/viewing-historical-metadata-of-bigquery-tables-datasets#comment122482298_69296811), to get the status of the dataset on a given time for the last 7 days, you can use [time travel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#query_data_at_a_point_in_time).

##### Metrics

To get some idea about the rows uploaded or the storage used in a dataset, you could use the GCP metrics, specifically [rows uploaded](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#bigquery/storage/uploaded_row_count) or [stored byted](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#bigquerystorage/stored_bytes).

##### Partition the table

Another possibility is to [partition the tables by ingestion time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ingestion_time). This will create a pseudocolumn in your table called `_PARTITIONTIME`, and you'll be able to run queries according to the ingestion time ([down to an hour granularity](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timepartitioning), according to the boundary limits for partitioned tables).

If you partition your tables, then you can query the rows inserted every hours with a query like:

```sql
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME as insert_time,
count(1) as count,
FROM `project-id.dataset-id.table-id` 
GROUP BY _PARTITIONTIME
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

If you want to know how many rows were at some point in time, you can run another query like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) as count
FROM `project-id.dataset-id.table-id`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME < TIMESTAMP("2016-04-15 08:00:00")
```

More examples in [the docs for partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_using_pseudo_columns).